# How to convert a set of Map keys to an Array List

Tags: java

How can I put a collection of my Map's keys as an Array List?

I am initializing the map as follows:

```
Map foo = new HashMap<Character,Integer>();
```

After adding values, I am trying to put my keys into an ArrayList as follows:

```
ArrayList<Character> bar = new ArrayList<Character>(foo.keySet());
```

However, the compiler is throwing the following error:

```
warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
ArrayList<Character> bar = new ArrayList<Character>(foo.keySet());
                                                                      ^
required: Collection<? extends Character>
found:    Set
```

I understand that it requires a conversion of the key's set, but I do not know how to implement this as all of the examples I've seen of keySet() follow the method I've used.

Comment: Supply generic types to your map: `Map<Character, Integer> foo = new HashMap<Character,Integer>();`

Comment: As an aside, it might be better to actually keep them in a `Set` rather than a `List` unless you're planning to either sort them or add duplicates. A `List` implies some sense of ordering, which you won't get by initializing your list via the `keySet` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use generics for the declaration of `foo`:

```
Map<Character,Integer> foo = new HashMap<Character,Integer>();
```

Then, `foo.keySet()` will have the correct generic type `Set<Character>`, fixing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Map foo` reference is not generic (it is raw), so compiler can't safely assume that it will always hold `HashMap<Character,Integer>` (it can also hold `HashMap<String,Integer>`).

Because of this `foo.keySet()` doesn't return generic `Set<Character>` as result, but raw `Set`, but 
constructor of `ArrayList<Character>` expects collection of `Character` (or collection of derived types from characters - in other words `Collection<? extends Character>`), which raw `Set` can't represent.

To solve this problem you need to explicitly set generic type in your `foo` reference, via

```
Map<Character, Integer> foo = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ - add this
```

Answer (score -1):

You need a set not a list to store your keys

```
Set<Character> bar = new HashSet<Character>(foo.keySet());
```

Comment: While using a `Set` might be more accurate, it's not required, and the results of `keySet()` can be added to a `List`, which is what OP is trying to do.